# How do I format a number stored in a string?

Tags: string, decimal

If I have numbers as a text string without decimal places, how can I convert it to 2 decimal places such that 12345 is converted to 123.45?  The string can be any length greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to your decimal type then divide by 100.

```
string stringVal = "12345";

decimal val = decimal.Parse( stringVal ) / 100M;

double val = double.Parse( stringVal ) / 100.0;
```

Convert it back to a string using

```
string newVal = string.Format( "{0:N}", val );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide it by 100.0.

```
x = int(x)
x /= 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are convinced that it is numeric and don't want to double check, then you can avoid the conversions:

```
if (stringVal.Length == 2)
{
    stringVal = "0." + stringVal;
}
else
{
    stringVal = stringVal.Insert(x.Length - 2, ".");
}
```

This assumes you want a leading zero if it's 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result as a string, you can just use string operations (examples in C#):

```
value.Substring(0, value.Length-2) + "." + value.Substring(value.Length-2)
```

If you want the result as a number, first parse the value then divide by 100:

```
double.Parse(value) / 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

decimal str=12345;
            (str/100).ToString("F");